# Java - Selenium PhantomJS RemoteDriver with proxy settings is not working

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I would like to use Selenium's RemoteDriver with PhantomJS with proxies + multi threading. My problem is that the RemoteDriver is not using the given proxy in my setup.

I tried the following 2 setups, both times I can see the correct proxy in the PhantomJS response, but it is still using my local IP.

In the CLI I start PhantomJS with: `phantomjs --webdriver=4444`

First setup:

```
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyHost);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities().phantomjs();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

try {
    this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
this.driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
```

As response PhantonJS says:

> [INFO  - 2014-12-26T10:29:42.902Z] Session
>   [1ade9c30-8cea-11e4-952c-61f83d60a6ec] - CONSTRUCTOR - Desired
>   Capabilities:
>   {"platform":"ANY","browserName":"phantomjs","proxy":{"httpProxy":"173.234.249.114:3128","noProxy":null,"socksUsername":null,"ftpProxy":null,"socksPassword":null,"sslProxy":null,"proxyAutoconfigUrl":null,"proxyType":"MANUAL","class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy","autodetect":false,"socksProxy":null,"hCode":1338671111},"version":""}
>   [INFO  - 2014-12-26T10:29:42.902Z] Session
>   [1ade9c30-8cea-11e4-952c-61f83d60a6ec] - CONSTRUCTOR - Negotiated
>   Capabilities:
>   {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.0","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.0.3","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"httpProxy":"173.234.249.114:3128","noProxy":null,"socksUsername":null,"ftpProxy":null,"socksPassword":null,"sslProxy":null,"proxyAutoconfigUrl":null,"proxyType":"MANUAL","class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy","autodetect":false,"socksProxy":null,"hCode":1338671111}}
>   [INFO  - 2014-12-26T10:29:42.902Z] SessionManagerReqHand -
>   _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 1ade9c30-8cea-11e4-952c-61f83d60a6ec

Second setup:

```
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyHost);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities().phantomjs();
ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=proxy");
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-type=http");
cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, proxy);

try {
    this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("nope");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
this.driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
```

As response PhantomJS says:

> [INFO  - 2014-12-26T10:36:38.259Z] Session
>   [12710f00-8ceb-11e4-952c-61f83d60a6ec] - CONSTRUCTOR - Desired
>   Capabilities:
>   {"platform":"ANY","phantomjs.cli.args":{"httpProxy":"173.234.249.114:3128","noProxy":null,"socksUsername":null,"ftpProxy":null,"socksPassword":null,"sslProxy":null,"proxyAutoconfigUrl":null,"proxyType":"MANUAL","class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy","autodetect":false,"socksProxy":null,"hCode":2130507747},"browserName":"phantomjs","version":""}
>   [INFO  - 2014-12-26T10:36:38.259Z] Session
>   [12710f00-8ceb-11e4-952c-61f83d60a6ec] - CONSTRUCTOR - Negotiated
>   Capabilities:
>   {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.0","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.0.3","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
>   [INFO  - 2014-12-26T10:36:38.259Z] SessionManagerReqHand -
>   _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 12710f00-8ceb-11e4-952c-61f83d60a6ec

As you can see both times the correct proxy address is used (`"httpProxy":"173.234.249.114:3128"`), but whatismyipaddress.com is reporting my own address.

When I use the `PhantomJSDriver` from [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver), then I can use the regular `org.openqa.selenium.Proxy`, but I'm not able to accomplish multi threading as described [here](http://blog.wedoqa.com/2013/07/how-to-run-parallel-tests-with-selenium-webdriver-and-testng-2/). With a PhantomJS process in the CLI and RemoteDriver at least multi threading works well.

Thanks for any advice! And sorry for the long text :)

```
--- UPDATE ---
```

Just found out that if I start PhontomJS directly in the CLI with the `--proxy` then it uses the given proxy, when I connect with RemoteDriver. One option would for me would be now simply to start multiple PhantonJS processes manually with a fixed proxy.